# How to use Alpine.data() in @push within Laravel Blade components?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, alpine.js

With Alpine.js 2 it was possible to develop Blade components with the following structure:

```
...
<div x-data="myApp()">
...
@once
    @push('child-scripts')
<script>
    function myApp() {
        return {
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
    @endpush
@endonce
```

This was great in that it allowed all the code for the component to be defined together.

In Alpine.js 3 this approach of defining functions is deprecated (https://alpinejs.dev/upgrade-guide#alpine-data-instead-of-global-functions). Instead, they should be defined like this:

```
...
<div x-data="myApp">
...
<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('myApp', () => ({
            ...
        }))
    })
</script>
```

However, it states "you need to define `Alpine.data()` extensions BEFORE you call `Alpine.start()`". This suggests that with the new approach it is impossible (or at best unreliable) to use @push to add data functions for use in Blade components and, therefore, impossible to keep all the code for a Blade component together.

My code all works fine with Alipne 3, if I use the deprecated approach. If I try to include the new syntax data function via @push, I get "myApp is not defined" JS error from my Blade component.

I am using Alpine.js 3.9 installed as an NPM module. I have also tried using Alpine.js 3 via `<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js" defer></script>`. The result is the same in both cases.

Is there a way to keep all the code together in the Blade component?

**UPDATE 25.02.2022**

It seems I need to provide more details of what I am doing so here they are.

The relevant bits of my app.blade.php are:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    @livewireStyles
    ...
</head>
<body>
    // HTML/Blade stuff here
    @livewireScripts
    @stack('child-scripts')
</body>
```

My app.js is like:

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
require('./bootstrap');
window.Alpine = Alpine
Alpine.start();
```

I have also tried:

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
window.Alpine = Alpine
Alpine.start();
```

My Blade component is like this:

```
...
<div x-data="myApp">
...
@once
    @push('child-scripts')
<script>
    document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('myApp', () => ({
            ...
        }))
    })
</script>
    @endpush
@endonce
```

**When I access a page that uses the Blade component, I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: myApp is not defined".**

If I revert my Blade component to the old syntax (as follows) it works with no errors:

```
...
<div x-data="myApp()">
...
@once
    @push('child-scripts')
<script>
    function myApp() {
        return {
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
    @endpush
@endonce
```

The only difference between the working and failing versions is the way in which myApp is defined. The deprecated method works but, with the new method, it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you would think that using `@push` is unreliable.

Since the `@push` directive (like any other blade directive) is evaluated by the blade engine on the server-side, by the time the page loads, anything you push is already there on the page.

One thing to note is that it is important to `defer` the execution of the javascript assets so that it is executed after the document has been parsed. You can do that by adding a `defer` attribute like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script> {{-- or CDN here --}}
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        @stack('scripts')
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
// resources/js/app.js

import Alpine from 'alpinejs'

window.Alpine = Alpine

Alpine.start()
```

I'm already using Alpine v3 this way without any issues.

Comment: I was not saying that @push is unreliable but that I thought it would be unreliable to use it with the new way of defining Alpine data. I use @push all the time. I have exactly the structure you have shown in your answer. If I leave my component with the now deprecated syntax, everything works with Alpine 3. If I change to the new syntax, I get "myApp is not defined". So my point is all about the new syntax using `Alpine.data()` via an `alpine:init` event.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clearer. The whole point is that I want to use @push but seem unable to do so with the new syntax.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the use of `@push` and what it means by having the Alpine data initialized before `Alpine.start()`. As long as you have the `defer` attribute in the js bundle, it doesn't really matter whether you put the `Alpine.data()` above or below it. I don't think the problem is related to the `@push`. I'm using the exact same version of Alpine with `@push` without any issues. Is it possible that the js bundle didn't get compiled correctly?

Comment: I have updated my question again to show more detail of what I am doing. Maybe you can see something in there that I am doing incorrectly. I don't know if the problem is related to @push or not. I just know that, since I changed it to the new method of defining data providers, it doesn't work and I don't know why.